# Long running MYSQL query, Frame Table and View with grouping

Tags: mysql, indexing, view, left-join

I have a table t_date_interval_30 that is cartesian product of a 365 calendar year of dates, and a time field incremented at 30 minute intervals.  I use this as a framework to hang call data on.

```
t_date_interval_30
DATE, DAYNAME, INTERVAL
'2013-01-01', 'Tuesday', '00:00:00'
'2013-01-01', 'Tuesday', '00:30:00'
'2013-01-01', 'Tuesday', '01:00:00'
'2013-01-01', 'Tuesday', '01:30:00'
'2013-01-01', 'Tuesday', '02:00:00'
'2013-01-01', 'Tuesday', '02:30:00'
ETC...
```

Next I have a view v_call_details that is a summarized view of the call data.  Call data is summarized down to one row per call session initiated - the source for this can have multiple rows per call session; i.e., call rolls Ring No Answer from one target to another, each leg of the call increments a new record row.

```
v_call_details
CLIENT, CSQ, SESS_ID, DATE, CALL_START, CONT_DISP, MET_SLA
'Acme','ACME_CSQ','123-123456789-01','2013-01-01','2013-01-01 00:12:34','ABANDONED',TRUE
'Acme','ACME_CSQ','123-123456998-01','2013-01-01','2013-01-01 00:45:02','HANDLED',TRUE
'Acme','ACME_CSQ','123-123457291-01','2013-01-02','2013-01-02 13:31:58','HANDLED',FALSE
ETC...
```

So, when I run the below query it takes forever.

```
SELECT
cd.`client`,
cd.`csq`,
di.`date`,
di.`dayname`,
di.`interval`,
count(cd.`sess_id`) AS `calls`,
(count(cd.`sess_id`) - sum(IF(cd.`cont_disp` = 'ABANDONED'
        AND cd.`met_sla` > 0,
    1,
    0))) AS `presented`
FROM
t_date_interval_30 di
    LEFT JOIN
v_call_details cd ON (di.`date` = cd.`date`
    AND di.`interval` = SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(cd.`call_start`) DIV 1800) * 1800))
WHERE
di.`date` BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-02'
GROUP BY cd.`csq`, di.`date`, di.`interval`
```

I have never really worked with indexes (though I have tried adding a few to the DATE values and CALL_START values).  When I run an EXPLAIN EXTENDED I get the below results.

```
id, select_type,    table,                      type,   possible_keys,  key,    key_len,    ref,    rows,   filtered,   Extra
1,  PRIMARY,        di,                         range,  i_date,         i_date, 3,          ,       96,     100.00,     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1,  PRIMARY,        <derived2>,                 ALL,    ,               ,       ,           ,       153419, 100.00,     ,
2,  DERIVED,        t_cisco_csq_agent_details,  ALL     ,               ,       ,           ,       161925, 100.00,     Using temporary; Using filesort
2,  DERIVED,        t_lkp_clients,              ALL     ,               ,       ,           ,       56,     100.00,     ,
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Right now if I run the query, returning results for 2 days worth of data takes roughly 70 seconds.  At that rate, doing a 90 day report will take an hour and a half... I need to find a way to bring that down.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't assume that 90 days worth of data will require 45 times the effort of 2 days.  Your query is doing a full scan of the call details table, and this may account for much of the effort.  MySQL can propagate the condition on date from `di` to `cd` through the equijoin.  I'm not sure if it does in this case (because of the second condition).

Second, you are using a view.  That might make it impossible to actually improve performance.  You can try, but you should try to write the query without the view.

My next question is how long does this take to run:

```
select cd.csq, cd.`date`,
       SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(cd.`call_start`) DIV 1800) * 1800)) as interval,
       count(*)
from v_call_details cd 
WHERE cd.`date` BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-02';
```

If this takes a reasonable amount of time, then test it for 90 days.  If that works, then you can do the aggregation first and then join back to the `di` table.  This is just an idea.  I suspect the real performance problem is in the view.